# STS Error: Could not publish server configuration

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat, vaadin

I m working with spring-tool-suite-3.2.0.RELEASE-e4.2.2-win32-x86_64, on a Maven vaadin-archetype-application with the Vaadin Plugin for Eclipse and Tomcat 7. Sometimes when I save some changes in my project, usually in a Composite, I see this error:

> Could not publish server configuration: C:\Users\diego\Documents\SPRING\WS.metadata.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\conf\server.xml (The requested operation cannot be performed on a file with a user-mapped section open).
>   C:\Users\diego\Documents\SPRING\WS.metadata.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\conf\server.xml (The requested operation cannot be performed on a file with a user-mapped section open)

The referenced file is a Apache tomcat 7 config file. Tomcat is working fine, I  just want to know how to stop this annoying message! Is this a problem?